# stream_context_get_params() is not a function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

i am using 'codeigniter-facebook-google-login' library

Fatal error: Call to undefined function stream_context_get_params() in /application/libraries/oauth2/Provider.php on line 203

the code is as following.......

```
$opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => http_build_query($params),));

$_default_opts = stream_context_get_params(stream_context_get_default());
$context = stream_context_create(array_merge_recursive($_default_opts['options'], $opts));

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$return = json_decode($response, true);
```

my php version is 5.4.38 on server as per the php document stream_context_get_params is supported greater than the 5.3.0v

any one know what is the problem or alternative of the problem...

Comment: I am having the same issue, even though my php version is correct. Please anyone post the answer if they know

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the library but the error is clear. Inspect the file "Provider.php" and ensure that either the function is declared somewhere in that file or that is requiring a file with the function that is missing. I am sure the function is available somewhere you just need to make it available in "Provider.php" and all will be good

Edit: as per your comment this is a native function of php 5.3> so if not available you must be running older version of php

Comment: `stream_context_get_params()` is an php function

Comment: I won't argue except to say it is not available. If it is a php function available in your version of php then you wouldn't get the error. So you have kind of answered your own question - check your php version as this function is 5.3>